# Integration with resect to counting measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am starting my journey in Measure theory, and I am having some troubles.
I was doing an exercise from my course notes.

Let $\mu$ be the cardinal measure over $\mathbb{N}$.

a)  Let $a:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by $a(n)=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2^n}$. Calculate, if possible, the following integral: $\int_{\mathbb{N}}ad\mu$

So, I began researching and testing some things. I took f a non negative function and, calling $f_n(k)=f(k)$ if

$1 \leq k \leq n$ and $0$ otherwise, which is a simple function! And using Lebesgue's monotone convergence theorem I ended with

$\int_{\mathbb{N}}ad\mu = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n) $.

Now, my actual function has negative values. My intuition tells me that I can use Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence theorem in a similar way to prove that I can do that integral by $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^n}$, taking the absolute value.

Also, in the problem they say "if possible". Part two of the problem is with $b(n)= \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}.  $ If I am right, and I can do that by doing the series, since $1/n$ diverges I can say that the integral diverges?

Comment: Yes, this is correct

Comment: Looks good. ${}{}$